# unecessary horizontal scrollbar displayed on overflow:scroll

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a website on a single page, with every section of the page taking up exactly the size of the user screen (using backstrech for backgrounds).
Like this: http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home

The problem comes when the user's screen height is too small to contain my page's content. In that case, I want my background to stretch more than the user's screen, as it has to fill the entire content's background.

So, I've been using overflow:scroll, which fix the entire problem **except** for displaying an annoying horizontal scroll bar, even when it is not needed. What I mean is, even at full-screen when there's no overflow at all, the horizontal scrollbar appears

This is my code:

```
section#page1 {
    background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll; }
```

Comment: Use `overflow: auto;`?! Or `overflow-y: scroll;`. Or `overflow-x: hidden;`. What have you tested before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
section#page1 {
    background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Didn't know I could separate x and y. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> section#page1 {
>    background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
>    -webkit-background-size: cover;
>    -moz-background-size: cover;
>    -o-background-size: cover;
>    background-size: cover;
>    height: 100vh;
>    overflow: auto;
> }
> ```